# for loop not looping correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is probably an easy problem, but my code is only executing the outer for loop at the end, and once at the beginning. It should loop over every combo for every combination of numbers

```
from itertools import permutations as p                                                                                                              
combos = p(['/','*','-','+'], 3)                                                                                          
numbers = p(['9','7','7','6'])                                                                                                                       
for y in numbers:                                                                                                                                    
    print(y)                                                                                                                                         
    for x in combos:                                                                                                           
        print(x)
```

What am I doing wrong? It outputs:

```
('9', '7', '7', '6')
('/', '*', '-')
('/', '*', '+')
('/', '-', '*')
('/', '-', '+')
('/', '+', '*')
('/', '+', '-')
('*', '/', '-')
('*', '/', '+')
('*', '-', '/')
('*', '-', '+')
('*', '+', '/')
('*', '+', '-')
('-', '/', '*')
('-', '/', '+')
('-', '*', '/')
('-', '*', '+')
('-', '+', '/')
('-', '+', '*')
('+', '/', '*')
('+', '/', '-')
('+', '*', '/')
('+', '*', '-')
('+', '-', '/')
('+', '-', '*')
('9', '7', '6', '7')
('9', '7', '7', '6')
('9', '7', '6', '7')
('9', '6', '7', '7')
('9', '6', '7', '7')
('7', '9', '7', '6')
('7', '9', '6', '7')
('7', '7', '9', '6')
('7', '7', '6', '9')
('7', '6', '9', '7')
('7', '6', '7', '9')
('7', '9', '7', '6')
('7', '9', '6', '7')
('7', '7', '9', '6')
('7', '7', '6', '9')
('7', '6', '9', '7')
('7', '6', '7', '9')
('6', '9', '7', '7')
('6', '9', '7', '7')
('6', '7', '9', '7')
('6', '7', '7', '9')
('6', '7', '9', '7')
('6', '7', '7', '9')
```

Comment: What would you prefer it output?

Comment: In Python 3, lots of things that used to return lists (including `itertools.permutations`) instead return generators.

Comment: Can you post an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

itertools.permutations produces an iterator. That means it can be consumed. Once consumed, a subsequent loop will just skip it. If you convert it to a list, you will have continued access to its members.

```
from itertools import permutations as p
combos = list(p(['/','*','-','+'], 3))
numbers = list(p(['9','7','7','6']))
for y in numbers:
    print(y)
    for x in combos:
        print(x)
```

Comment: how can I get around this

Comment: @PAS set `combos = p(...)` inside the inner loop.

Comment: @quapka why would we want to recalculate the permutations at each outer iteration?

Comment: @kojiro I guess it depends, what is more time consuming - whether iterating over list, or creating the generator each time. @PAS asked `how can I get around this`, that's why I answered..